# SQL - select max of duplicated items with different value

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have a situation like this:

```
name, age
Tom, 30
Tom, 30
Sam, 35
Sam, 34
...
```

I would like to remove duplicated id, but if their value (in this case age has different values) I would like to keep the max. So my output should be like this:
name, age

```
Tom, 30
Sam, 35
```

Obviously, SELECT DISTINCT won't work.
Any suggestion, on how to handle this situation?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to *aggregate* the data with the same name and, in particular, you are searching for the max, then you can use the corrispondent *aggregation function*

```
select name, max(age) from table group by 1
```

Comment: Thank you , didnt think it would be so simple